# Applescript how to print results in double quotes?

Tags: macos, applescript

I need to print into a dialog, or copy in the Mac's clipboard, the following result (simple html code) after running a working Applescript code. There are 3 variables filenamevariable, dimension1variable & dimension2variable:

```
img src="filenamevariable" width="dimension1variable" height="dimension2variable"
```

I'm having probs publishing the variables in double quotes as above.

Can anyone please suggest me the Applescript code to print(dialog) or copy into clipboard, above html code after script is run? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppleScript strings are delimited exclusively by double quotes.  Literal quotes inside a string must be escaped by way of a preceding backlash.  AppleScript identifiers need to be parsed outside of a string in order for a distinction to be made between text and code.  So, it involves concatenation several string components together, and this can be done in a few ways.

The most typical and simplest way is to concatenation using the `&` operator.  I would personally change the HTML double quotes to single quotes, since it has the luxury of using either:

```
set imgTag to "<img src='" & ¬ 
          filenamevariable & ¬ 
               "' width='" & ¬ 
        dimension1variable & ¬             
              "' height='" & ¬
        dimension2variable & "'>"
```

If you want to use double quotes in the HTML, then escape them:

```
set imgTag to "<img src=\"'" & ¬ 
            filenamevariable & ¬ 
               "\" width=\"" & ¬ 
          dimension1variable & ¬             
              "\" height=\"" & ¬
          dimension2variable & "\">"
```